# How to uninstall livecom

Tags: 13.04, plugins

I use outlook.com as my primary mail service. After updating ubuntu to raring, I went to check my mail. There was this prompt to install livemail which allows me to get email notifications on desktop. It integrated with mail service and shows up in the mail icon on system bar.
Problem is, I want to remove it now. I tried synaptics pkg manager and removed all packages which I deemed were related to it. Still, there it sits, as if nothing has happened.

Some help please?

Note: Please don't post comments on how I should check something before installing. I liked it but now want to remove it.

**Edit**: Found the answer! I searched for all files named similar to livecom and deleted

```
~/.local/share/applications/livecommaillivecom.desktop
```

which removed the mail icon from my system bar.

Comment: "Which you deemeed".  Right, think for a moment on what "you deemed related" is, and what "is actually related to it" may mean.  Then answer this: What exactly did they give you when you hit "yes" to installing livemail?  A .deb file?  A .bin file?

Comment: It means I removed a couple of packages having live-mail and live-com in their names. I think I was safe in assuming they belonged to it. It was installed as soon as I responded to prompt. No deb, no tar, no nothing.

Answer (score 2):

### How to obliterate livemail webapp from your system

Enter `sudo apt-get purge unity-webapps-livemail` in a terminal

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it didn't work. The icon still sits there and opens firefox with outlook.com loaded up

Comment: It removes the integration, but not the shortcut.

Comment: To remove the shortcut, find it in the dash, and drag it to the trashcan.

Comment: Drag it how? It lists when I click the mail icon in system bar. I want to remove it from there.

Comment: Thanx. Your suggestion was very helpful. I manually deleted .desktop file from applications folder. It solved the issue.